# LC3 Conversion from 16 bit to Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, binary, lc3, disassembly

How would I go about converting a given 16 bit string of 1s and 0s into Assembly language, and then output it onto the console? For example: Convert 0001001010000011 into "ADD R1 R2 R3".

Comment: That depends on the instruction set, and what do you mean by "16-bit string of 1s and 0s"? What's the character-encoding? Please provide more details.

Comment: @Dai It says LC3 quite clearly ;)  The instructions are 16 bit, he wants to write a disassembler. Better question is, does the disassembler also have to be in LC3 assembly?

Comment: Sorry! I'm in a basic Computer Engineering class and we've been spending the whole year learning LC-3 assembly language. So the code would use the LC-3 instruction set (ADD, NOT, LDR, STR, etc...) with registers R0 to R7. For the 16-bit string of 1s and 0s, I provided an example. Thanks!

Comment: @Jester Yes exactly I need to write a disassembler, and it all has to be written in LC-3 assembly.

Comment: And where did you get stuck? You just need to chop off the first 4 bits which identify the instruction, then write the 16 functions that can decode the appropriate one.

Comment: Well I know how to chop off the leftmost bit and analyze that, but I cant figure out how to chop off the 4 leftmost bits. Then I figured I would just write a separate subroutines for each of the 16 different instructions like you suggested, and jump to a certain subroutine if, for example, the value of the 4 leftmost bits = #1. (Jump to the ADD subroutine).

Comment: Chop off the first bit, convert it to 0/1 by subtracting the ascii code of `0`, then shift it left (add it to itself) then bring in the next bit and so on.

Comment: @Jester Can you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981266/how-to-increment-a-letter-in-string-in-lc3